# C# Change Variable Name By Values in For Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, for-loop, tostring

I have 4 `string List` variables:

```
var cat1 = new List<string>();
var cat2 = new List<string>();
var cat3 = new List<string>();
var cat4 = new List<string>();

if (value== "1")
{
    cat1.Add(value.ToString());
}

else if (value== "2")
{
    cat2.Add(value.ToString());
}

else if (value == "3")
{
    cat3.Add(value.ToString());
}

else if (value== "4")
{
    cat4.Add(value.ToString());
}
```

Instead of using 4 `if-else`, can I use `for-loop` by changing variable names in each loop increment?

Such as:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    cat[i].Add(value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: wait, do you want to add `value.ToStrong()` to **all** of your lists? Why don't you just add it then to one-by-one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place your lists in array and use indexes from 0 to 4 in for loop:

```
var cat1 = new List<string>();
var cat2 = new List<string>();
var cat3 = new List<string>();
var cat4 = new List<string>();

var cat = new[] { cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4 };

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    cat[i].Add(value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: your code will add `value.ToString()` to **all** of this lists. Why don't you just `var v = value.ToString(); cat1.Add(v); cat2.Add(v); cat3.Add(v); cat4.Add(v);`?

Comment: @vasily.sib thank you for your advice. I have implemented it.